# pronunciation for 'Hermione'

Tags: pronunciation

Wikipedia says Hermione’s pronunciation is [/hərˈmaɪ.əni/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermione_Granger). But I hear **/hərˈmaɪ.ni/** in the audio. Would you check the audio for my better understanding of the sound?

[[audio]](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/144)

Comment: Considering that this word is rarely used, especially by whom are learning English, I voted to close as Too Localised, although I was unsure whether to vote as Off Topic.

Comment: http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2003-07-10/features/0307100218_1_audio-book-harry-potter-first-books

Comment: @Carlo Hermione is the name of one of the main characters in a series of books that has sold *450 million copies*, and since it's both popular and easily available in translation, a lot of learners use Harry Potter as parallel text.  Heck, I did the same thing--I bought Harry Potter in Japanese to learn from :-)  I think you can make an argument that it's not too localized.

Comment: Sorry @snail and Listenever. OK, I'm wrong. The fact is that I have heard that word only in reference to Greek mythology, not having read that book and not having talked of it with other people.

Comment: The third syllable is there in the audio, but it's very much diminished, overpowered by the strong stress on the second syllable.  In the US, the third syllable would be more obvious.

Comment: I used to work with a Hermione.  She did hate it when people called her 'Her-me-own'.  Apparently that's a common mistake.

Comment: @snailplane Not to mention the highest-grossing film series of all time: $7.7 billion dollars.

Comment: @Listenever Jim Dale chose one pronunciation for Hermione when he began reading the books, and the movies chose another.  He switched over to the movie pronunciation after the first movie came out, which I think was when he was reading either book four or five.  He also pronounced Voldemort differently in the early books!  Unfortunately, there's not always one *correct* pronunciation when it comes to names, so this happens relatively frequently.  The same thing happened with Dresden Files--James Marsters ended up changing his pronunciation for Marcone in book two.

Comment: @snailplane I don't have enough rep here to vote to reopen, but [your defense](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3685/pronunciation-for-hermione?rq=1#comment4825_3685) is compelling. There is a strong case for reopening this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @barbarabeeton says, the schwa is very light in this reading.

But what really distinguishes this reading from the Standard pronunciation is that the reader suppresses the second element of the /aɪ/ diphthong. The schwa (which is actually a reduced rounded vowel, [ᵿ]) **substitutes** for the [ɪ] in the diphthong.

This is probably occasioned at least in part by the fact that ['aɪ.ᵿ] is not a part of the ordinary English phonological repertoire; *Hermione* is a name of Greek origin.

I have observed this before in some BE speakers: it is very close to my own East Alabama dialect, where /aɪ/ is pronounced /a/ in open syllables and before voiced consonants, nasals and laterals. Except for the /r/, which is pronounced in my dialect, this is exactly how I would say *Hermione* if I were back home.